# How to count in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this query in mySQL where I would like to sum the line product of each doctor but I dont know how to do it.

```
use avant_medical;

select 
sales.doctor_id as DoctorID,
line_products.id as LineProductID,
line_products.name as LineProductName


from `doctors` 
inner join `sales` on `doctors`.`id` = `sales`.`doctor_id` 
inner join `inventories` on `sales`.`id` = `inventories`.`sale_id`
inner join `products` on `inventories`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
inner join `line_products` on `products`.`lineProduct_id` = `line_products`.`id`


order by `doctors`.`id` asc;

 
lPID= lineProductID
|DrID|lPID |
| -- | ----|
| 1  | 7   |
| 1  | 6   |
| 1  | 6   |
| 1  | 7   |
| 1  | 7   |
| 1  | 7   |
| 1  | 6   |

This is how I want:

Doctor 1
lineID | quantity
  7    |    4
  6    |    3
```

I try this query only in mySQL

Comment: You need to provide the schema to show how the data is being stored

Comment: It looks like you want to *count* not *sum* but it's not clear. Sample data will help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword you are looking for is `count`, not `sum`. Summing would add up every `lineProductID` as if they where regular mathematical values, while counting will add up how many times a given `lineProductID` is found.

```sql
select 
    sales.doctor_id as DoctorID,
    line_products.id as LineProductID,
    line_products.name as LineProductName,

-- We count the number of occurrences of each line_product.id
    COUNT(line_products.id) as LineProductQty

from `doctors` 
    inner join `sales` on `doctors`.`id` = `sales`.`doctor_id` 
    inner join `inventories` on `sales`.`id` = `inventories`.`sale_id`
    inner join `products` on `inventories`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
    inner join `line_products` on `products`.`lineProduct_id` = `line_products`.`id`

-- Never forget to properly GROUP your aggregate functions, such as COUNT() or SUM()!
GROUP BY sales.doctor_id, line_products.id, line_products.name

order by `doctors`.`id` asc;
```

Since you didn't provided full schema to test this, [I made a small, very artificial demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WdwLd8EL), but should be representative of how the query above works.